# disable zoom on active item of bottom navigation menu android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

How to disable zoom on active item of bottom navigation menu android studio?

[image]

Here the magnifying glass icon is larger than the rest. How to make it the same size as the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using google material bottomnavigation then try below code

`<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"/>`

If not work then try below steps:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
...
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

and on dimen.xml just add this line

```
<resources>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```